# javascript websockets error

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

I Have a simple setup witH a pytHon server running on a raspberry PI inside my Home network. On my PC I Have a basic HTML page witH some Javascript tHat sHould communicate witH tHe py server on my raspberry pi. THe  server on tHe raspberry pi works perfect wHen tested from telnet on my PC.

Here is tHe PytHon code:

```
import socket
from time import*

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ""
port = 51025
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print "Connection open"
print conn, addr
while 1:

    data = conn.recv(4096)
    if data:
        print "msg received"
        conn.sendall(data +" 12 uniflu")
    else:
        print "connection lost"
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print "Connection open"
        print conn, addr
```

This is the javascript code:

```
window.onload = function() {

  // Get references to elements on the page.
  var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
  var messageField = document.getElementById('message');
  var messagesList = document.getElementById('messages');
  var socketStatus = document.getElementById('status');
  var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');
  var openBtn = document.getElementById('open');

  // The rest of the code in this tutorial will go here...

  // Create a new WebSocket.
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.81:51025');
// Close the WebSocket connection when the close button is clicked.

// Show a connected message when the WebSocket is opened.
socket.onopen = function(event) {
  socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Connected to: ' + event.currentTarget.URL;
  socketStatus.className = 'open';
};

// Handle any errors that occur.
socket.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error: ' + error);
};


// Close the WebSocket connection when the close button is clicked.
closeBtn.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Close the WebSocket.
  socket.close();

  return false;
};
// Show a disconnected message when the WebSocket is closed.
socket.onclose = function (event) {
        var reason;
        alert(event.code);
        // See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-7.4.1
        if (event.code == 1000)
            console.log( "Normal closure, meaning that the purpose for which the connection was established has been fulfilled.");
        else if(event.code == 1001)
            console.log("An endpoint is \"going away\", such as a server going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.");
        else if(event.code == 1002)
            console.log("An endpoint is terminating the connection due to a protocol error");
        else if(event.code == 1003)
            console.log("An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a type of data it cannot accept (e.g., an endpoint that understands only text data MAY send this if it receives a binary message).");
        else if(event.code == 1004)
            console.log("Reserved. The specific meaning might be defined in the future.");
        else if(event.code == 1005)
            console.log("No status code was actually present.");
        else if(event.code == 1006)
           console.log("The connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or receiving a Close control frame");
        else if(event.code == 1007)
            console.log("An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received data within a message that was not consistent with the type of the message (e.g., non-UTF-8 [http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629] data within a text message).");
        else if(event.code == 1008)
            console.log("An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a message that \"violates its policy\". This reason is given either if there is no other sutible reason, or if there is a need to hide specific details about the policy.");
        else if(event.code == 1009)
           console.log("An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a message that is too big for it to process.");
        else if(event.code == 1010) // Note that this status code is not used by the server, because it can fail the WebSocket handshake instead.
            console.log("An endpoint (client) is terminating the connection because it has expected the server to negotiate one or more extension, but the server didn't return them in the response message of the WebSocket handshake. <br /> Specifically, the extensions that are needed are: " + event.reason);
        else if(event.code == 1011)
            console.log("A server is terminating the connection because it encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.");
        else if(event.code == 1015)
            console.log("The connection was closed due to a failure to perform a TLS handshake (e.g., the server certificate can't be verified).");
        else
            console.log("Unknown reason");

        $("#thingsThatHappened").html($("#thingsThatHappened").html() + "<br />" + "The connection was closed for reason: " + reason);
    };

// Send a message when the form is submitted.
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Retrieve the message from the textarea.
  var message = messageField.value;

  // Send the message through the WebSocket.
  socket.send(message);

  // Add the message to the messages list.
  messagesList.innerHTML += '<li class="sent"><span>Sent:</span>' + message +
                            '</li>';

  // Clear out the message field.
  messageField.value = '';

  return false;
};

// Handle messages sent by the server.
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  messagesList.innerHTML += '<li class="received"><span>Received:</span>' +
                             message + '</li>';
};

};
```

WHen I load tHe HTML page in my firefox browser, I can see tHe connection being made in pytHon by tHe printout, but after tHis tHe server becomes unresponsive. I also see tHe error message 1006 in tHe browser. Does anyone know tHis area and can Help me? WHy does it work very well from putty and not from tHe web browser?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but check out socket.io, they simplify websockets a lot.

Comment: Why are all your 'h's capitalized?